# Add IOS capability programmatically in Cordova plugin

Tags: ios, node.js, xcode, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have developed a plugin for Cordova IOS, for using App Groups.

The plugin needs to activate App Groups Capability under `Targets` -> `Capabilities` in **XCode** and select one of the `App Groups`.

If I activate it manually, it works well, but I would like to activate it programmatically, well in `plugin.xml`, or with a custom hook.

Somebody have achieved that?

Comment: I think you can archive that with hook, you need to add/edit a Entitlement.plist file onbeforebuild to solution, containing the AppGroup capability (like push capability on xcode8). entitlement.plist is supported and autogenerated since cordova-ios 4.3.0. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-11854

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following to the `plugin.xml` file then remove and reinstall the plugin. The capability will still need to be added to the provisioning profile(s), but Xcode should resolve that automatically if you build using the GUI or use the `-allowProvisioningUpdates` flag with `cordova build ios`/`xcodebuild`.

```xml
<platform name="ios">
    <config-file target="*.entitlements"
            parent="com.apple.security.application-groups">
            <array><string>group.com.example</string></array>
    </config-file>
    <config-file target="**/Entitlements-Debug.plist"
            parent="com.apple.security.application-groups">
            <array><string>group.com.example</string></array>
    </config-file>
    <config-file target="**/Entitlements-Release.plist"
            parent="com.apple.security.application-groups">
            <array><string>group.com.example</string></array>
    </config-file>
</platform>
```

Comment: After 3 years :D

Comment: @Del please feel free to mark this as correct if it worked for you!

Comment: Hi @noodleofdeath, as I don't remember why I needed that or where I was going to use it, I cannot say if this is correct. If someone needs this now and comments that is correct, I will approve for next people.

Comment: @del turns out this requirement was necessary for a project I was just assigned last month

Comment: @Víctor it's correct, confirmed working. Xcode also handles auto-provisioning. We've been touched by the grace of the flying spaghetti monster.